Girl's father is kidnapped and she gets revenge
A girl's father kidnapped and the girl tries to find him... She meets a guy who teaches her how to fight (I think he is like a kung fu master, samurai or something like that ). Also a man from the police helps her too.
She finally finds her dad but when she goes to save him, they understand her and catch her... so they bring her dad in the same room and the man who kidnapped her father breaks her father's neck in front of the girl... After that she manages to escape.
She learns that the man who killed her father waits for the daughter to come on a ship... So she goes there to find the man who killed her father and when she finds him she breaks his neck.
I think the movie is Asian, Korean or something like that. The movie has a lot of fighting... These are some parts of the movie, if anyone knows the name, help...

Sounds like Street Fighter: The Legend of Chun-Li (2009) with Kristin Kreuk and Michael Clarke Duncan:

When a teenager, Chun-Li witnesses the kidnapping of her father by wealthy crime lord M. Bison. When she grows up, she goes into a quest for vengeance and becomes the famous crime-fighter of the Street Fighter universe. 

She's trained in martial arts by a man called Gen and later helped by an Interpol agent called Nash. Bison breaks her father's neck in front of her, but she gets back at him in the end by breaking his neck

in front of his daughter.

Here's the trailer:



